# Iterating through an array produces 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io

I have an array that adds clients' names and displays the array as a list. The function `myFunction` iterates through the array's items to post them as a list.

However, whilst this works, [it always displays 'undefined' first, before any names](https://ibb.co/vmLgkbX), and I believe this has something to do with either `txt` or `value`; if I remove `txt` from `txt = txt + value + "<br>";`, then the most recent item in the array is displayed, rather than all items.

How can I remove the 'undefined' from appearing?

script.js:

```
socket.on('theitems', function (data) {
    data.forEach(myFunction);
    var txt = "";
    function myFunction(value) {
          txt = txt + value + "<br>"; 
          $('.dispUser').html(txt); };
      console.log(data);
    });
```

In this case, `data` refers to the array from the server.

`console.log(data)` doesn't show undefined in the array, so, it must be something in the iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txt = ""` is being executed *after* the forEach call.  You're appending to txt and iterating on data before it is defined.
Either move `var txt=""` to the top, or
Check to make sure it is defined and use the empty string if it isn't defined:
`txt = (txt||"") + value + "<br>";`

Also, you can use map and join:

```
$('.dispUser').html(data.map(val=>`${val}<br>`).join(''));
```